# how to add values at the end of datatable?

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I am getting some data in unstructured form. So i want it to be in structured form. So i take datatable in this i have added two columns, i.e. "field" and "value". Now i added first row in data along with the data in these two columns. But the prob is its replacing the old data every time i come again to save the data in this datatable. My code is:

```
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Field", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(val.Substring(0, val.IndexOf(":") + 1), val.Substring(val.IndexOf(":") + 1, val.Length - val.IndexOf(":") - 1))
```

Comment: What kind of application is it ? Desktop, web application ? If you are creating the DataTable each time, it will only contain one row. Can you show a bit more of the context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DataTable, you have to create a new row before adding it:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Field", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

var row = dt.NewRow();
dt["Field"] = "FieldName";
dt["Value"] = "Value";
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

[NewRow() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) :

> You must use the NewRow method to create new DataRow objects with the
>   same schema as the DataTable. After creating a DataRow, you can add it
>   to the DataRowCollection, through the DataTable object's Rows
>   property. When you use NewRow to create new rows, the rows must be
>   added to or deleted from the data table before you call Clear.

But if you are only handling a key/value pair, why don't you use a `Dictionary<string, string>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are u using this in a loop? only the last line should be in the loop otherwise youre instantiating the datatable each loop.

Comment: you can say its loop but what i want as i m getting the new value that should added at the end of the datatable as creating new row.